# R: Transform data frame into pseudoCSV

Tags: r, transformation

let's have a two column data frame like this:

```
A  1
A  2
A  4
A  5
B  2
B  13
C  1
C  3
C  6
C  18
D  8
E  2
E  112
...
```

Is there a quick method in R how to transform it to such two columns dataframe?

```
A  1;2;4;5
B  2;13
C  1;3;6;18
D  8
E  2;112
```

And how to put it back to the first structure again?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option would be (comments from @David Arenburg)

```
res1 <- aggregate(Col2 ~ Col1, df1, paste, collapse = ";")
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
res2 <- setDT(df1)[, list(Col2=paste(Col2, collapse=";")), Col1]
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
res3 <- df1 %>%
           group_by(Col1) %>%
           summarise(Col2= paste(Col2, collapse=";") )
```

#### Update

To convert the output back to the original structure

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(res2, 'Col2', ';', 'long')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "D", "E", "E"), Col2 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 13L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 18L, 8L, 2L, 112L)), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2"),
 class =     "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Answer (score 0):

`paste()` with `collapse = ";"` is used in `aggregate()` to concatenate V2. To return it to the original structure, `strsplit()` is used to split V2 in `lapply()` - `do.call()` is just to bind the resulting list row-wise.

```
df <- read.table(header = F, text = "
A  1
A  2
A  4
A  5
B  2
B  13
C  1
C  3
C  6
C  18
D  8
E  2
E  112")

df1 <- aggregate(df, by = list(df$V1), FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse = ";"))[,-2]
names(df1) <- c("V1", "V2")
df1
#  V1       V2
#1  A  1;2;4;5
#2  B     2;13
#3  C 1;3;6;18
#4  D        8
#5  E    2;112

df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(df1$V1), function(x) {
  df <- data.frame(x, strsplit(df1[df1$V1 == x, 2], ";"))
  names(df) <- c("V1", "V2")
  df
}))
df
#   V1  V2
#1   A   1
#2   A   2
#3   A   4
#4   A   5
#5   B   2
#6   B  13
#7   C   1
#8   C   3
#9   C   6
#10  C  18
#11  D   8
#12  E   2
#13  E 112
```

Comment: @akun Your post didn't have a way to return to the original structure when I wrote the answer.